# Issues using/setting up a wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, connection

I recently purchased a LinkSys router from a local resale shop. It appears to be an older model and the only things it came with were a power supply and Ethernet cable (no manuals or any such).

There was a piece of paper taped on the router with a link to an owner's manual; however, the link didn't seem to get me any helpful information regarding setup or anything. So this is my issue... I have connected this thing to my modem and attempted to run it a few times, my iPod typically recognizes it, but it doesn't work from there (it doesn't require a password, marks that I have connected but I can't access the internet).

So, my question is this... What do I need to do to set this device up? Was there a disk with drivers that I needed? I own two other routers - I've had this same issue with one of those - and the one (which I didn't set up either) works flawlessly. What am I missing?

**P.S.** I will have additional router details soon, I do not have access to it at this time. I will also include the link that I was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset a Linksys router, hold the "Reset" button for 30 seconds; the Power button should blink as you do this. Release the button, and then unplug the router from the wall for another 30 seconds. Plug the router back in. Connect your computer via Ethernet and log in to the Linksys router using the default settings.

Once reset, you need to reconfigure the WAN settings.  Log into the router by going to 192.168.1.1, and use "admin" as the password. Leave username blank.  If you're using PPPoE, which most people do, you will need the username and password from your service provider.  This is usually written on the contract that you signed when you ordered the service.

Don't forget to change the Username and Password to gain access to the router under the 'Administration" tab.

Comment: Alright, after some amount of fiddling, I got to that page and was able to change the password from admin to something else. However, whenever I try to apply any changes, it goes to a black screen with a white box.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reset the router to factory settings:

http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=139791

Once you have reset it, you'll need to log in to the router and do some basic configuration for the wireless network. There are a lot of settings that could be leftovers on this thing that would keep it from working. Regardless, a factory reset and re-setting up the wireless network should fix it.

Comment: Sadly, that is not what my router looks like, I wouldn't know where to find the reset button (I will check when I get home though).

Comment: The reset button is usually pretty universal-- it will be a small recessed button with "Reset" above it. You may need a pin or pencil to press and hold it in. You'll be able to find it pretty quickly.